# External onClick function trigger on link page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that is currently opening an anchor within multiple elements on a click on a toggle directory page using onClick.

The problem is this link only works on this page, and I would like an external link pointing to this page to operate this function.

Simply put:

Page 1.

```
<a href="#windsorcorporate">Link to windsor corporate>/a>
```

Page 2.

```
<a href="#windsorcorporate" onClick="elm = document.getElementById('box5.1'); elm.style.display = 'block'; elm = document.getElementById('box5.1.5'); elm.style.display = 'block'; elm = document.getElementById('box5.1.5.1'); elm.style.display = 'block'; openClose('a5');">Windsor, Ontario</a><br />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question.. just select your code and click on Ctrl+K  to convert to code .. to let us know clearly what you need

Comment: move your js to an external file and link to it from all pages

Comment: Sorry Mohamed, hope this is better!